# Why is rand giving me almost identical (but slightly different) numbers each time

Tags: c++, random, random-seed

I wrote the following piece of code to generate random numbers in c++

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 5
#define MAX_VAL ARRAY_SIZE*5+1

int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));

  int arr [ARRAY_SIZE];
  for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
    arr[i] = (rand() % MAX_VAL);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
    printf ("%d\n", arr[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When I run this I get *almost* identical numbers each time:

```
tyler@Tylers-MacBook-Pro hw2 % ./MergeSort
11
16
16
21
16
tyler@Tylers-MacBook-Pro hw2 % ./MergeSort
21
11
21
11
6
tyler@Tylers-MacBook-Pro hw2 % ./MergeSort
6
6
1
16
6
tyler@Tylers-MacBook-Pro hw2 % ./MergeSort
16
1
16
6
21
tyler@Tylers-MacBook-Pro hw2 % ./MergeSort
1
21
21
11
21
tyler@Tylers-MacBook-Pro hw2 % ./MergeSort
1
21
21
11
21
tyler@Tylers-MacBook-Pro hw2 % ./MergeSort
11
16
1
1
11
tyler@Tylers-MacBook-Pro hw2 % ./MergeSort
11
16
1
1
11
tyler@Tylers-MacBook-Pro hw2 % ./MergeSort
21
1
6
6
1
```

Why is my random number generator only giving me the values: 1, 6, 11, 16 and 21?  This makes no sense to me.  I made sure to seed it and the numbers aren't always in the same order which is what makes this even more confusing.  As a side note I am using OSX.

Comment: It's because `rand()` is trash. Don't use it. Use [C++ random number generators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that actually work.

Comment: `rand()` is trash, but that isnt the reason

Comment: Stop using `srand`/`rand` in new code. Use the modern facilities available in the [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header. See also [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Comment: `(rand() % MAX_VAL)` introduces bias unless `MAX_VAL` can be perfectly divided into `RAND_MAX`.

Comment: `time(*anything*)` is a horribly bad seed.

Comment: @idclev463035818 True, but `#define` is also trash and has no business being in C++ code either if you can avoid it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: My personal issue with STL's presentation is the seeding suggestions (the `std::mt19937 mt(std::random_device{}())` equivalent on slide 22). Seeding 19937 bits of randomness with a 32 bit number should not be normalized...but here we are I guess.

Comment: @TravisGockel Sure, the seeding could/should be better in real life, but I guess he needed something that would fit on a slide ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `MAX_VAL` is defined as `ARRAY_SIZE*5+1`, not `(ARRAY_SIZE*5+1)`. This means that your use in `arr[i] = (rand() % MAX_VAL);` expands to:

```
arr[i] = (rand() % 5 * 5 + 1);
```

There aren't a lot of options (only 5 possibilities), which is why you're seeing the same numbers. You can fix this by parenthesizing the definition of `MAX_VAL` or making it a contant variable:

```
const unsigned int MAX_VAL = ARRAY_SIZE * 5 + 1;
```

A secondary issue is the use of `srand(time(NULL))`. On most systems, [`time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) will return the same value if the program is run in the same second. This means running the program in rapid succession (within the same second) will yield the same results. It is preferable to use the PRNG facilities in [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out the two primary issues in this code, but it's worth showing the C++ way of doing things here for contrast and to un-learn a lot of the C thinking that broke this code in the first place.

The C++ version of this code side-steps a lot of the problems here by using facilities C++ has and C lacks:

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  // Define constants instead of using #define, as this avoids interpolation syntax issues
  const size_t array_size = 5;
  const int max = array_size * 5 + 1;

  // Use the C++ random number generator facilities
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 gen(rd());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, max);

  // Use a dynamically sized array
  std::vector<int> arr;

  for (int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i) {
    arr.push_back(dis(gen));
  }

  // Use C++ container iteration to simplify code
  for (const int& i : arr) {
    // Use streams for output
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your using of `#define MAX_VAL`

The actual calculation is `rand() % 5 * 5 + 1`, which means, you first modulo the rand() result with 5, and then multiple by 5, and then add 1.

I assuming you mean to write `rand () % (5 * 5 + 1)`
That can be resolved by:

```
#define MAX_VAL (ARRAY_SIZE * 5 + 1)
```